# A punish-mental thing

Tags: lateral-thinking

You get punishment if you cannot do the work.

You even get punishment if you can do the work.

What is the work and what is the punishment?

Comment: Isn't that every-day work? If you're bad, you're fired, and if you're good, you just get more work to do...

Comment: The work is one and only one for the question. And the punishment is also one and only one for the question.

Comment: Somebody's already got the Monday blues, @Xenocacia

Comment: Sorry don't understand line 2 - do you get punishment for being able to do the work - or for doing the work - it looks like you get punishment for just being able to do the work 'you even get punishment if you can do the work' -- DO you mean instead 'you even get punishment if you do the work'???

Comment: Work: Solving a dispute regarding a bet, notably a poker game, while being the organizer/dealer.

Answer (score 11):

The work is:

> **Living**

The punishment is:

> **Death**

Because:

> If you cannot live, you will die.
>  If you *do* live, you will (eventually) die.

Comment: Wow. Dark but true

Comment: @North - yeah, a bit dark to be considering the journey as work. That's why I'm kind of certain this isn't the actual answer.

Comment: Somebody's getting the birthday blues.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's the answer, but worth a shot.

The work:

> Political Leader

The punishment:

> Blame

Reasoning:

> If they do a bad job - they get blamed for everything, if they do a good job - they *still* get blamed for everything

Comment: So true so true. Though not all country have a president, so maybe write "political leader"

Answer (score 5):

Well, I find this intriguingly straight forward here, but I'm not sure whether it's what is being looked for.

So I'll have a go at this.

> The work is : A killing contract by some mafia leader maybe ! 
> Obviously, if he does accomplish his job, he gets punished by the judicial system and the law, and if he fails to do so, the one who assigned him the task invariably punishes him.

Answer (score 3):

The work is

> Parenting

The punishment is:

> Stress

Reasoning:

> Well, parenting (from what my mom tells me) is a 24 hour, nonstop, acclimated stress, with absolutely no payment besides white hair and financial deficit. When you are a parent, you are punished with stress from kids. However, you still get stressed even without parenting (bills, studies, overdue IRS taxes, etc.)

Comment: +1. Tough weekend with the kids at home? :-)
Edit: LOL at your reply!

Comment: I am that kid at home :P   Edit: I think I've given my mom more white hair than I can count